# Cortana not always shuffling music when asked

Tags: 8.1, music, cortana

When I ask Cortana to "shuffle all music", sometimes it works yet sometimes I still get my songs played in alphabetical order. Why is this? Is there a special instruction I should say so I can get my songs in random order?

I'm running Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: When Cortana responds to you, does the text always say *"shuffle music"*? If not, she may not be hearing you fully.

Comment: @caschw I checked and it does.

Comment: Even when it plays alphabetical?

Comment: @caschw Yes. In fact, if I say `play all music` sometimes it will play it in random order. So it seems no matter how I ask for music, she ends up deciding if the list should be random or not.

Comment: To be pedantic, alphabetical order is *one* random order (as is in album order)

Comment: Did you piss her off? :D On a more serious note, what is the version of Windows you are running? 8.1 or 10?

Comment: @slayernoah 8.1. I edited the question.

Comment: Are the songs played in alphabetical order often or just happened only once or twice? Also how many songs do you have?

Comment: @slayernoah Actually I can't remember when I last had that problem so maybe it got fixed in an update since I posted this. One thing I still see happening though is that using "shuffle" voice command will have the list begin with the same song about 3 times out of 5, and that song happens to be the first in alphabetical order. The other songs however appears to be in complete random order.

Comment: When Cortana responds to you ?  does the text always say *"shuffle music"*? If not, she may not be hearing you fully.  Even when it plays alphabetical?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, as Rowland Shaw points out, there is a small change that a random list will be an alphabetical list and thereby playing the music in an alphabetical order is random. Cortana is just playing with you, It's a part of her personality :)

Answer (score 1):

List of Cortana Music Commands:

- Play artist (Play Alicia Keys)
- Play song title (Play We are the Champions)
- Play genre (Play Jazz)
- Play playlist (Play Old School Rap Playlist)
- Play album (Play Ready to Die)
- Pause the music
- Resume the music
- Play the next track
- Play the previous track
- Shuffle the music
- What song is playing?